# Getting an error dialog box while connecting to firebase and the message in dialog box is "Application not found"

Tags: android

Getting an error dialog box while connecting to firebase in android studio and the message in dialog box is "Application not found"[It is the dialog box I am getting while connecting to firebase in Android Studio](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jEyyo.png)

Answer (score 0):

As per the message, you should check your client id and package name. The Google JSON file you are using to connect to the server is not having valid information